# Is this a proper use of "diagnostician"?

Tags: medical, professions

Just a touch of background, this is for a button label in a piece of software. A user presses the button in order to choose the type/specialty of the health care provider that diagnosed them with an injury.

I want to use the phrase "SELECT DIAGNOSTICIAN" as a label on this button, but when I search Google, it appears that the proper meaning of "diagnostician" is someone with a *specialty in diagnosis*, and so I feel that I'm using the word inaccurately.

Is it acceptable to refer to a non-specialist giver of a diagnosis as a diagnostician? Is there a more appropriate word that doesn't imply a specialty in the act of diagnosis itself?

Comment: According to this dictionary at least, "diagnostician" can be the specialism (ie a doctor who specialises in diagnosis) or anyone who has given a diagnosis (which i think is the meaning you want).  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diagnostician  Ultimately, though, I think this is a UX question, so you should be thinking of what the user of the site will think rather than dictionary definitions.

Comment: And what type and/or nationality of user is the software aimed at?  That will surely affect the terminology used.  Altho' I can obviously guess the intended meaning, I'm not familiar with the term "diagnostician" in British English.  If your software may be used by non-Americans, or people whose first language is not English, or any lay people, then you may want to consider using more explanatory terminology.

Comment: It would be targeted towards American/Canadian users. And yeah, I'm considering something like "CARE PROVIDER TYPE" over "DIAGNOSTICIAN"... It just still feels sloppy somehow.

Comment: What are some of the types/specialties of the health care provider?

Comment: You may have a procedural problem. How many steps precede this "button"? I'm a software testing and documentation writer type.

Comment: Making self-service hospital admissions software, some fool used the correct button label but no average person knew what was meant by "triage." Take Away: Correct isn't right.

Comment: In the above example at the Montreal General Hospital, the button didn't change; but, a full-time person stands beside the machine and after asking the "user" what's wrong, presses the button for the "user." The button is labeled, "Triage." When you press the button, you are given a number to prioritize your wait to see a nurse to determine "what's wrong." ; (

Answer (score 1):

**What's correct is not always right.**

Begging the question; How would a wounded, preoccupied, and lay (ignorant) person comprehend what you're asking? How would that individual even know what kind of a person or who to summon?

Q: What kind of a doctor would you want for a metatarsal contusion? A: ?

Q: What's wrong? A: I need a "doctor."
(I've never heard, "I need a diagnostician" or "I need a health care worker" or "I need a Health Care Specialist."

Consider using common labels that the ***actual user*** would understand?

Rather than use words that even professionals can't agree on, how about "Start" or "Begin" for the first button? (Even *Help* is implied since you're there already.) It isn't as easy as it might seem at first.

EDIT: Your intended use of the phrase is somewhat redundant on a button. A button is a selection by its presence and implied function. When you press a button you have made a selection. It stands that "diagnostician" by itself would suffice.

If there were several buttons available each with single words such as diagnostician, janitor, cashier, announcer, pilot, etc. it would still work since pressing one will be a selection, in fact.

In either case, "select" is unnecessary, yet proper.

Rather than specify the title of some professional, is there a step or process that the user would recognize such as "Examination" or "PAIN relief" or "EMERGENCY" or "Stop BLEEDING" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps be a bit more specific and add a word to "SELECT DIAGNOSTICIAN" if you want to avoid the confusion.

For example: "SELECT HEALTH CARE DIAGNOSTICIAN".

Comment: I don't know about that phrase specifically, since in this case it's already clear that a diagnostician is some kind of health care provider. Also, I don't have the button real-estate for a phrase that long, but that's a UX problem, not an English one.